# How do I test a website without opening it using automation?

Tags: selenium, automation, html

I am able to use Selenium web driver to test the website and get the result. But I need to get the result without opening a single web page. I made some R&D and found Selenium can't do this. 
Can any body tell me how can I achieve this?

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: Have a look at [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/)

Comment: You should try phantomJS, [slimmerJS](https://slimerjs.org/), and [Chrome headless](http://www.buaban.com/software-testing/selenium-with-chrome-headless/).

Comment: IMO, the Ghost Browsers are meant for Data Science not for Web Application testing. Through Automation we basically automate the manual repetitive tasks. Manual Testing requires a standard & stable browser. Thanks

Comment: "But I need to get the result without opening a single web page"  one question... - why

Answer (score 0):

Give Htmlunitdriver a try

Enter this line in your code

```
driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
```

true = to enable javascript support.

In case you'll see many warnings in your console once you run your test. To ignore them simply do this

```
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware");
log.setLevel(Level.OFF);
driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
```

Else there is always other options like PhantomJS

Source: [SoftwareAutomata](https://softwareautomata.wordpress.com/2017/08/07/selenium-headless-with-htmlunitdriver/)